# Flutter: How to use Checkbox on Popup Dialog Form

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to understand recomposition.

I have a list of items with edit buttons.  When the edit button is clicked, a popup modal form appears with two textboxes and a checkbox.  I can't get the checkbox to update when it's clicked.  What am I doing wrong?

```
// main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Two ListViews',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF2196f3),
        canvasColor: const Color(0xFFfafafa),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key, key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  bool _checkbox = false;

  void _showForm() async {

    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 5,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (_) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            // this will prevent the soft keyboard from covering the text fields
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 120,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _titleController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _descriptionController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description'),
              ),

              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Item is Checked: ',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),

                  // *********** Checkbox won't update on screen **********
                  // But the value toggles correctly in the print statement
                  Checkbox(
                    value: _checkbox,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _checkbox = !_checkbox;
                        print("*** isSwitched = $_checkbox");
                      });
                    },
                  ),

                ],
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pop-Up Checkbox'),
      ),
      body:

        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            Flexible(
              child:
              ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                children: [

                  Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("List Item 1"),
                      trailing: SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: () => _showForm(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),

          ]

      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _showForm(),
      ),

    );
  }

}   // End class _MyHomePageState
```

Thanks for your help!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey setState will not update state of bottom sheet because bottom sheet is not part of your StatefulWidget for this you need to use `StatefulBuilder` and then call setState like below-

```
 void _showForm() async {

    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 5,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (_) => StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter myState) =>Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            // this will prevent the soft keyboard from covering the text fields
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 120,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _titleController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _descriptionController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description'),
              ),

              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Item is Checked: ',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),

                  // *********** Checkbox won't update on screen **********
                  // But the value toggles correctly in the print statement
                  Checkbox(
                    value: _checkbox,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      myState(() {
                        _checkbox = !_checkbox;
                        print("*** isSwitched = $_checkbox");
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Harish - there are soooooo many widgets to get to know!